# Unable to find accuracy of the model using MASE

Tags: r, forecasting

I am new to R programming and Forecasting field as well. I'm learning from the book **Forecasting: Principles and Practice by Rob J Hyndman, George Athanasopoulos** and it's a very resourceful book.

In chapter 11, they discussed about Hierarchical and Grouped time-series forecasting. Specifically in section 11.4, they have used Australian Tourism data set to perform grouped time series forecasting. When checking the accuracy using MASE, I got some warnings followed by "NaN" values.

Also in 11.6, with reconciliation approach, I got the same error while calculating MASE values To avoid error, I tried to update packages, mention package name before accuracy function, but none of them solved the issue.

Used `R` code is same as the one in the book and attached [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSm2E.png) for reference. Let me know, if you need anything else.

It would be helpful to me, if you could offer you suggestions.

This online textbook is free for everyone.
[Book](https://otexts.com/fpp3/), [Section 11.4](https://otexts.com/fpp3/tourism.html), [Section 11.6](https://otexts.com/fpp3/prison.html)